# Page anchors without trailing filetype, ie: www.example.com/sub#mySection

Tags: html, xhtml

So I need to link to things like a section with id="mySection" at

```
www.example.com/sub/
```

But since the page generated in wordpress and there is not any actual directory /sub/, nor any index.html or what have you inside it, how can I link to a specific part of the rendered page?

Safari does nothing however when I create an anchor like this:

```
www.example.com/sub#mySection
```

nor when I do it like this:

```
www.example.com/sub/#mySection
```

It works in firefox, just not safari.
Thanks you.
Joe

Comment: Is there an anchor on the page with the name mySection? e.g. <a name="MySection" />

Answer (score 1):

Both those formats work fine for me in Safari 4.  Perhaps something else on the page is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> www.example.com/sub#mySection

That should work actually. If you have a section on your site, with id='mySection'...

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the anchors into http://www.example.com/sub/#mySection somehow works now. Oh well.